# Rudin's RCA $5.17$ proposition

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

There is the proposition:

Let $V$ be a complex vector space.
(a) If $u$ is the real part of a complex-linear functional $f$ on $V$, then
$$f(x)=u(x)-iu(ix)$$ for all $x\in V$.

There is the proof:

If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are real numbers and $z$ $=$ $\alpha$ $+$ $i\beta$, the real part of $iz$ is $-\beta$.

This gives the identity

$z$ $=$ $Re z$ $-$ $iRe(iz)$

for all complex numbers $z$. Since

$Re(if(x))$ $=$ $Re$$f(ix)$ $=$ $u(ix)$,

$$f(x)=u(x)-iu(ix)$$ follows from $z$ $=$ $Re z$ $-$ $iRe(iz)$ with $z$ $=$ $f(x)$.

I don't understand how is the real part of $if(x)$ and $f(ix)$ equal of $u(ix)$ ?

If we suppose that $f(x)$ $=$ $u(x)$ $+$ $iv(x)$

then the real part of $if(x)$ and $f(ix)$ is supposed to be $-v(x)$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You have by definition that $\def\Re{\operatorname{Re}}$ $\def\Im{\operarorname{Im}}$ $u(x)=\Re f(x)$. In particular $$u(ix)=\Re f(ix).$$ As $f$ is linear, $f(ix)=i\,f(x)$.

Precisely because $v(x)=-u(ix)$ is that you get the formula $$f(x)=u(x)-i\,u(ix).$$